# How to analyze each element array?

Tags: php, arrays, web, foreach, web-development-server

how can i analyze each element of an array?

```
$carrello;
```

`echo $carrello` is equal to 5,5,6,7 so the array.
How can i do something like this:

```
foreach ("element of the array") {
echo 'item found';
}
```

Comment: so `$carrello` is actually a comma delimited string? just explode it and load it in your foreach like you normally would do.

Comment: up-voted back to zero~: we all have to start somewhere!

Answer (score 1):

I think your looking for something like this:

```
//If $carrello is comma delimited string
$carrello = "5,5,6,7";
$carrello = explode(",", $carrello);

foreach($carrello as $key => $value)
    echo $key . "=>" . $value . "<br />";

//If $carrello is an array
$carrello = array(5,5,6,7);

foreach($carrello as $key => $value)
    echo $key . "=>" . $value . "<br />";
```

Output:

```
0=>5
1=>5
2=>6
3=>7
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is a two step process, firstly, you need to turn the string in to an array:

```
$carrello_array = explode(',', $carrello);
```

The second step is to loop over them.  The easiest way is to do:

```
foreach($carrello_array as $carrello_entry) {
    //do some analysis here
}
```

Hopefully that helps, let us know if you need any more help

Comment: Ok, thank you! but how can i know when the array is finished? (sorry for my english, i'm italian )

Comment: @LuigiDaddario The `foreach` loop goes trough every element of the array and end's after it's done! you don't have to check anything

Comment: @LuigiDaddario Also i would recommend you to read a book or watch a basic tutorial about php. (A goo reference: php.net)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$array = explode(",", $carrello);
foreach($array as $value){
  if(!empty($value)){
    echo $value;
  }
}
```

Variable $carrello contains comma separated values.

explode method will convert the values in the variable $carrello using comma as the delimiter.

in the loop if the value not empty will be echoed.

Comment: Adding some explanation about what this code does and why it solves the asker's problem wouldn't hurt.